# How to find all solutions for : $a^3 \equiv b^3 \pmod{7^3}$, knowing that $7 \nmid ab$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, eisenstein-integers

> Find all integers $a$ and $b$ such that $$a^3 \equiv b^3 \pmod{7^3}\,,$$ knowing that $7 \nmid ab$.

As a try, I noticed that, since $\gcd(b, 7)=1$, there exists $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b\cdot x \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \Rightarrow b^3 \cdot x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7^3}$. Thus $a^3\equiv b^3 \pmod{7^3} \iff (ax)^3\equiv 1\pmod{7^3}$. After this I tried to use Euler's totient function, but I do not know where I should begin.

Comment: you might try to exploit the fact that $a^3 - b^3$ is divisible by $7^3$.

Comment: $18^3\equiv1\bmod7^3$

Comment: (a-b)(a2+ab+b2)=0(mod 7^3) then since 7 can’t divide a-b we have 7^3 divides a2+ab+b2. Then I don’t know, perhaps try a2+ab+b2-7^3=0 and solve it as an equation?

Answer (score 1):

Given $7\nmid ab$, $a^3\equiv b^3\bmod 7^3\iff (a/b)^3\equiv1\bmod 7^3$.

Let $x\equiv a/b\bmod 7^3$.  We are looking for $x$ such that $7^3|x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Now if $7|x-1$ and $x^2+x+1$, then $7|x^2+x+1-(x+2)(x-1)=3$, a contradiction.

So $7^3|x-1$ (i.e., $x\equiv1\bmod7^3$) or $7^3|x^2+x+1$.

Now we are looking for $x$ such that  $x^2+x+1\equiv0\bmod7^3$.

Note that $x\equiv 2$ and $x\equiv 4$ are the solutions to $x^2+x+1\equiv0\bmod7$.

If $x=7k+4$ is a solution to $x^2+x+1\equiv0\bmod7^2$, then $k\equiv2\bmod7$, so $x\equiv18\bmod7^2$.

If $x=7^2k+18$ is a solution to $x^2+x+1\equiv0\bmod7^3$,

then $k\equiv0\bmod7$, so $x\equiv18\bmod7^3$.

If $x=7k+2$ is a solution to $x^2+x+1\equiv0\bmod7^2$, then $k\equiv4\bmod7$, so $x\equiv30\bmod7^2$.

If $x=7^2k+30$ is a solution to $x^2+x+1\equiv0\bmod7^3$,

then $k\equiv6\bmod7$, so $x\equiv324\bmod7^3$.

(I could have argued that, if $x\equiv18$ is a solution,

then $x^4+x^2+1\equiv x+x^2+1\equiv0$, so $x^2\equiv18^2=324$ is a solution too.)

So either $a\equiv b$ or $a\equiv18b$ or $a\equiv324 b\bmod 7^3$, and then $a^3\equiv b^3\bmod 7^3$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Proposition.**  For two integers $a$ and $b$, $$a^3\equiv b^3\pmod{7^3}$$ if and only if at least one of the following conditions holds:
>
> - $a\equiv 0\pmod{7}$ and $b\equiv 0\pmod{7}$,
> - $a\equiv b\pmod{7^3}$,
> - $a\equiv -19b\pmod{7^3}$, and
> - $a\equiv 18b\pmod{7^3}$.

For integers $a$ and $b$, $a^3\equiv b^3\pmod{7^3}$ if and only if $$(a-b)\,(a^2+ab+b^2)\equiv 0\pmod{7^3}\,.$$
If $7\mid a-b$ and $7\mid a^2+ab+b^2$, then it follows that
$$3ab=(a^2+ab+b^2)-(a-b)^2\equiv 0\pmod{7}\,,$$
whence $7\mid 3ab$, so $7\mid ab$.  This means $7\mid a$ or $7\mid b$.  However, as $7\mid a-b$, we conclude that $7\mid a$ and $7\mid b$.  Thus, $a^3\equiv 0\equiv b^3\pmod{7^3}$ in this case.  From now on, we assume that $7\nmid a-b$ or $7\nmid a^2+ab+b^2$.

In the case $7\nmid a^2+ab+b^2$, we conclude that $7^3\mid a-b$.  Therefore, $a\equiv b\pmod{7^3}$, but $7\nmid a$ and $7\nmid b$.  The only remaining case is when $7\nmid a-b$.

When $7\nmid a-b$, we get $7^3\mid a^2+ab+b^2$.  Thus, $7\mid a^2+ab+b^2$.  Now, observe that
$$a^2+ab+b^2\equiv (a-2b)(a-4b)\pmod{7}\,.$$
That is, $a\equiv 2b\pmod{7}$ or $a\equiv 4b\pmod{7}$.

Suppose that $a\equiv 2b\pmod{7}$.  Then, $a-2b=7k$ for some integer $k$.  Therefore,
$$a^2+ab+b^2=(2b+7k)^2+(2b+7k)b+b^2=7\left(b^2+5kb+7k^2\right)\,.$$
Because $7^3\mid a^2+ab+b^2$, we deduce that
$$7^2\mid b^2+5kb+7k^2\,.$$
Therefore, $$b(b-2k)\equiv b^2+5kb+7k^2\equiv 0\pmod{7}\,.$$  However, we can easily see that $b\not\equiv 0\pmod{7}$.  This implies
$$b\equiv 2k\pmod{7}\,.$$
Write $b-2k=7l$ for some integer $l$.  Then,
$$b^2+5kb+7k^2=(2k+7l)^2+5k(2k+7l)+7k^2=7(3k^2+9kl+7l^2)\,.$$
Thus, we need $7\mid 3k^2+9kl+7l^2$.  Consequently,
$$3k(k+3l)\equiv 3k^2+9kl+7l^2\equiv 0\pmod{7}\,.$$
Because $b-2k=7l$ and $7\nmid b$, we conclude that $7\nmid k$, whence $$k\equiv -3l\pmod{7}\,.$$
Therefore, $k=-3l+7m$ for some integer $m$, whence
$$b=2k+7l=(-3l+7m)+7l=l+14m$$
and
$$a=2b+7k=2(l+7m)+7(-3l+7m)=-19l+77m\,.$$
Thus,
$$a=-19(b-14m)+77m=-19b+343m\equiv -19b\pmod{7^3}\,.$$

Now, suppose that $a\equiv 4b\pmod{7}$.  Then, $a-4b=7k$ for some integer $k$.  Therefore,
$$a^2+ab+b^2=7(3b^2+9kb+7k^2)\,.$$
Again, we can see that
$$3b(b+3k)\equiv 3b^2+8kb+7k^2\equiv 0\pmod{7}\,.$$
Ergo, $b\equiv -3k\pmod{7}$.  Let $b=-3k+7l$ for some integer $l$.  Then,
$$3b^2+9kb+7k^2=7(k^2-9kl+21l^2)\,,$$
whence
$$k(k-2l)\equiv k^2-9kl+21l^2\pmod{7}\,.$$
Thus, $k\equiv 2l\pmod{7}$.  Write $k=2l+7m$.  Therefore,
$$b=-3k+7l=l-21m$$
and
$$a=4b+7k=4(l-21m)+7(2l+7m)=18l-35m\,.$$
Finally, we may write
$$a=18(b+21m)-35m=18b+343m\equiv 18b\pmod{7^3}\,.$$

**Remark.**  In principle, there should be a more concise solution using Eisenstein integers.  I just opted for an elementary solution.

Comment: Is it valid to say simply that, since OP granted $7\nmid ab$, $a^3\equiv b^3\bmod 7^3\iff (a/b)^3\equiv1\bmod7^3$, and that means $a/b\equiv1\bmod7^3$ or $(a/b)^2+(a/b)+1\equiv0\bmod7^3$, and that last equation can be solved by solving $\bmod 7$ and lifting?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Yes, I had that in mind, but since the explanation of the "lifting" would go very much the same way as what I did, so I decided to do what I did, and not did what I could have done.  Do you understand what I just wrote?

Comment: Thank you.  I hope you don't mind if I post an alternative answer where I do what you could have done ;-)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  I welcome different answers.  No worries.